# Why $xy=N\Rightarrow (((x−1)p−1\text{ mod }N)−1)\text{ mod} X=0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

Experimentally, I found that for $N=xy;\ 3<x<y$ where $x,y$ are prime numbers and for prime numbers, $p>x$ the below expression is **always** true:

$$\Big(\big((x-1)^{p-1}\text{ mod }N\big) -1\Big) \text{ mod } {X} = 0$$

Why is it this way? And is it indeed true for all the $p,x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p$ is an odd prime, we have $$(X-1)^{p-1}\equiv (-1)^{p-1}=1\mod X$$

Set $$u:=(X-1)^{p-1}\ modulo \ Y$$.

Suppose $$Xs\equiv 1\mod Y$$ and $$Yt\equiv 1\mod X$$ then $$q:=(Xsu+Yt)\ modulo \ N$$ satisfies $$q\equiv Yt\equiv 1\mod X$$ and $$q\equiv Xsu\equiv u\mod Y$$

The chinese remainder theorem states then $$(X-1)^{p-1}\equiv q\mod N$$ so $(X-1)^{p-1}$ modulo $N$ is $q$. Now $q-1\equiv q-YT\equiv 0\mod X$ , hence $X$ divides $q-1$ completing the proof.

Comment: Wow, that looks cool! What do you think about the other part of the question, is it just luck or there is something there?

Comment: Thank you, what is the gcd in the other part ? $x$ , $y$ , either $x$ or $y$ ?

Comment: Yeah, either $x$ or $y$, it's basically factoring $n$

Comment: Please recheck the second result ? I do not get the desired congruence. Moreover, $p$ is not prime in this example.

Comment: Neither do I get the desired gcd in the first example

Comment: Sorry, $p$ was set to $p-1$ by mistake, it's value is good now.

Comment: I also added a small Java code to evaluate it, so there is no place for mistakes

Comment: Now, everything is correct!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea for the second part. But I think that it is more than just luck. Maybe it helps to see examples that DON''T work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69091/discussion-between-ilya-gazman-and-peter).