# Found a method for factoring numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, factoring, prime-factorization

Let $N$ be the number that we want to factor such that $N=xy$ where $x,y$ are primes and $0<x<y$

By experiment, I found a function that can factor such numbers, please help me prove that it indeed can factor any such number and may be other numbers as well.

So here we go: By experiment, I found that in 80% of the time, there is an integer $i$ such that $\gcd(f(i),n)$ equals to $x$ or $y$

$$f(i)=i^{p-1}-1\ \text{ mod }N$$

- $p$ is a prime number such that $p > x$
- $0<i<x-1$

Note that we don't need to know $x$ in order to satisfy $p>x$. Since $x<y$ implies $x<\sqrt{N}<y$, so we can pick $p>\sqrt{N}$

Also, I found that if $\gcd(f(i),N)$ equals to $x$ or $y$ then for every $k$ such that $i<k<x-1$. $\gcd(t(k),N)=\gcd(f(i),N)$

$$t(k)=f(i)\cdot f(i+1)\cdot f(i+2)...f(i+k)$$

So if we take random values of $k$ near by $\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$ for each value of $gcd(t(k),N)$ we calculate we will have 80% to factor $N$

Note that $(x-1)^{p-1}-1\mod{n}$ is always divisible by $x$ as prooven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531054/why-xy-n-rightarrow-x%E2%88%921p%E2%88%921-text-mod-n%E2%88%921-text-mod-x-0).

Here are few examples of my tests:

$x=1462691, y=415577, N=607860737707$
$p=779749$

$gcd(28^{p-1}-1\mod N,N)=y$

---

$x= 847213, y=209449, N=177447915637$
$p=421273$

$gcd(167^{p-1}-1\mod N,N)=y$

I wrote a small Java code that demonstrates this algorithm, I been able to solve integers up to the size of $2^{60}$. Quadratic-Sieve, for example, can solve integers of the size $2^{230}$ in the same time.

The biggest problem with this idea is that I don't know how to calculate $t(k)$ efficiently(here is a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531431/how-to-simplify-fx-n1a-1n2a-1n3a-1-nxa-1-mod-m) about it), I do it recursively at the moment.

**Please help me prove that this is indeed a factoring method!**

Java code:

```
BigInteger root = SqrRoot.bigIntSqRootCeil(n);
for (int j = 0; ; j++) {
    BigInteger a = ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        BigInteger bigI = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        BigInteger result = bigI.modPow(bigPrime.subtract(one), n).subtract(ONE);
        a = a.multiply(result).mod(n);
    }
    BigInteger gcd = a.gcd(n);
    if (gcd.compareTo(ONE) > 0 && gcd.compareTo(n) < 0) {
        System.out.println(gcd + " with " + bigPrime);
        return;
    }
    bigPrime = root.add(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
}
```

Comment: On the two bullet points regarding the definition of $f(i)$
1. "$p$ is a prime number such that $p>x$"  
2. "$0<i<(x−1)$"
How can you refer to $x$ at this point in your argument you do not know what it is yet? Also sometimes you refer to N and other times n.

Comment: @JamesArathoon I updated $N$. Note that $x<\sqrt{N}<y$

Comment: Ok that still leaves how you determine that $i<(x-1)$

Comment: @JamesArathoon just take values for $i$ that are close to 0

Comment: If $P_{prod}$ is the product of all the primes between 3 and floor($\sqrt{N})$, given $x<\sqrt{N}<y$, then $gcd(P_{prod},N)=y$. You presumably are seeking a way of calculating $P_{prod}$ without having to do $\pi(floor(\sqrt{N}))$ multiplications; where $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes less than or equal to n.

Comment: @JamesArathoon it sounds like you are missing something. Take a look at the second example, you need to examine less than 200 numbers to solve it

Comment: 100% of the time there is an i such that gcd(i,N)=x where 0<i<x+1.

Comment: @O.S.Dawg yep, because $i=x-1$ yeild $gcd(f(i),N)$ equals to $x$, a more interesting range would be $0<i<x-1$

Comment: Sorry mistake my comment above should read $gcd(P_{prod},N)=x$. In your two examples you have $x>y$ which is the opposite of what you say at the start..

Comment: In the first example $Floor(\sqrt{N})=779654$, GCD[28^(779749 - 1) - 1, 779654!]=53774392932659406380700377109254732301164946166486942245, if you factorize this you will find there are just 17 prime factors in common. Below 779654 there are 62,441 primes.

Comment: IntegerLength[779654!]=4255049, IntegerLength[28^(779749 - 1) - 1]=1128419 (Mathematica Functions) The full factorial (not optimised in any way) has only four times as many digits as your f(i) number in the first example.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: For the sake of computing something, that range is not more interesting; it's only two elements smaller. Two elements is completely negligible as compared to the size of the interval you're working through!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method by which your approach factors $N$ is by solving the problem:

- Find a $(p-1)$-th root of unity modulo $x$ (or modulo $y$).

If $i$ is such a thing modulo $x$ but not modulo $y$, then you have $\gcd(f(i), N) = x$.

The method by which you solve this problem is:

- Pick a range of consecutive integers. Hope one of them is a solution.

Of course, $(p-1)$-th roots of unity tend to be rare. In the worst case, if $\gcd(p-1, x-1) = 2$, then you will *only* succeed if you happened to pick a number that is $\pm 1 \bmod x$ (but not modulo $y$).

In your analysis, you recognize this; by picking $k \approx \sqrt{N}$ and testing $k$ consecutive numbers, basically what you are doing is guaranteeing that your interval contains *every* residue class modulo $x$, and consequently it must include all of the $(p-1)$-th roots of unity.

Once we recognize what your algorithm is doing, it's clear that it's quite wasteful; with much less work you could just compute

$$ t(k) = i \cdot (i+1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (i+k) \pmod N $$

and try to factor by computing $\gcd(t(k), N)$.

Alternatively, we could try to better exploit the idea of finding $(p-1)$-th roots of unity. It's clear that picking $p$ prime is the wrong thing to do; what you want is for $p-1$ to have a large common factor with $x-1$, and you have a better chance of that by making $p-1$ a product of lots of small numbers.

Then, rather than exhaustively searching for a root of unity (or randomly), we could instead try to *construct* one. This basically leads to [Pollard's p-1 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm).

Comment: Wow man, this is awesome! I am going to read more about Pollard ;)